# Grafana Loki Create dashboard with same graph then explore page

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-loki

I’m trying to create dashboards with Grafana Loki.
I have to reproduce this exact graph that is by default on the page explore:

[image: default graph]

I also tried to group the logs by level but the result is completely different

[image: my graph]

Does anyone know how to retrieve the query that is executed to recreate default chart?